# How is crystal frequency set?

Tags: crystal

When you purchase a crystal to use as a clock, the company is asking you exact frequency to set it at.

I remember needing a crystal that was 4x the NTSC color carrier and they were asking me how many digit precision I needed.

What is the process to 'set' the crystal output so precisely?

Comment: Choice of material and grinding or selection.

Comment: The precision question was asked to me by DigiKey; it would seem odd that they would process the part mechanically to make it fit the specs.

Comment: They would either pick the right component, or they would actually ask the manufacturer to do that. Also, there's programmable digital VCOs, but these are far more than just a crystal...

Comment: @Thomas - presumably they have already processed parts with varying levels of precision.  4 x NTSC colour burst frequency (or equivalent for PAL colour bursts) is a *very* common crystal that can be purchased at a wide variety of precisions.  For example, this is the frequency of the crystal used in the original IBM PC and clones of it, so was mass-produced for many years for this purpose.

Comment: There is are two variables, the tolerance at room temp and the AT temperature curve which is calibrated in ['] minutes or 1/60th of a degree that affects the slope of the 3rd order polynomial temperature sensitivity and total swing over a defined range.

Comment: It's clear from the accepted answer that you're using the wrong words in the question. Anyone answering your literal question would be wrong, so I'm voting to close this as _unclear_. Maybe it could be salvaged if you ask about an actual product.

Comment: I agree that it is a bit ambiguous since I didn’t know what kind of product it was; I remembered that we needed a crystal and digikey was asking me the precision; I was wondering if it was programmable or adjusted through some other process. In a way both answers are accurate. While we can close this as unclear I think the answers from Dave and Ali are bringing informative content.

Comment: Possibly of interest: https://youtu.be/b--FKHCFjOM

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I believe there could be some confusion. When you use a crystal as a "clock", you need "clock generator" for this. To get a real quartz crystal tuned to customer's specification, the order must be for many thousand units. It is very likely that OP means "programmable crystal oscillator", there are thousands models, see [Digi-Key for examples](https://www.digikey.com/products/en/crystals-oscillators-resonators/programmable-oscillators/169).

[image]

These devices are made in the standard SMT ceramic cases, 4-pins, 3x5mm or smaller, just as the usual fixed-frequency crystal oscillator chips. However, the programmable ones have some base oscillator, and a PLL circuit, with ability to externally program its parameters to almost any desired frequency. The typical output range is 1 Mhz to 110 Mhz. The chips usually have programmable non-volatile memory, re-programmable maybe only two or four times, and frequency can be specified down to 10-digit accuracy or something.

When purchasing, you can specify your own frequency (that's where they can ask for this), or you can purchase a [PC-based programmer](http://www.hk-electronics.com/pdf-0c/ECS-PCPRO.pdf) for this, and program you values.

Comment: I think that’s exactly what it was because the digikey guy asked me about the exact frequency just before they shipped the parts

Answer (score 7):

Coarse tuning is done in the grinding process, where the thickness of the quartz wafers is established. I once visited a manufacturing facility; the grinder operators were using ordinary shortwave receivers to monitor the broad peak of electrical noise that the batch of wafers emitted due to the grinding action. When it reached a point slightly higher than the target frequency, they would stop.

Fine tuning is done during the plating process that puts the electrodes on the wafer; adding metal brings the frequency back down. This process is much more precise, and each crystal can be individually calibrated.

Answer (score 1):

Since you said it was a 4x NTSC crystal, it was likely a standard part made in bulk. How they select the precision there is an issue of *binning*.

For this process, the factory produces a batch and then tests the crystal frequencies. Due to random process variations, the frequencies will have a distribution (a spread) across the ideal frequency.

If you order a highly precise crystal, they will pick it out of the stock of crystals lie close to ideal. They will charge you more for this. If you can tolerate a wider variance, they will sell you those that lie further away at a discount.

For example, this [crystal datasheet](https://www.diodes.com/assets/Datasheets/FF.pdf) says you can order the product in tolerances of ±10, 20 or 30 ppm.

This is common in a wide variety of processes, e.g. LED color and brightness, CPU speeds/number of cores, DRAM & FPGA speeds, etc.